# How to construct complex Google Web Search query?

Tags: http, search-engine, google-search

Searching through the Web by using the [Google](http://www.google.com) search engine is a *de facto* standard for Internet users.
Google provides a *basic* or an [*advanced form*](http://www.google.com/advanced_search) to prepare a query string to its search engine. Supposing to be interested in not using the web form, one can simply do an HTTP get request to the specific URL with a query string constructed upon the search conditions.

For instance I can search for results with word "*hello*" by doing an HTTP request at:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=hello
```

I can add another word, e.g. "*world*", as follows:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=hello+world
```

You know, the search can be more "complicated" by specifying nice parameters like:

- or condition(s)
- exact phrase(s)
- search on specific domain(s)
- avoid a specific word(s)
- search with a specific language
- limit search by geographical area
- search for document type
- etc.

How can I modify the query string to account for the above search parameters?

Comment: I hope you are aware that not using the web form and scraping the results pages violates googles terms of use.

Comment: @Filburt Thank you! You remembered it to me! However, my question concerns how to make something, not know if  this violates the Google terms! I'm testing a prototype. Google is already capable to defend itself from me :)

Answer (score 5):

I carefully examined the answers by [Pratik Chowdhury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691072/pratik-chowdhury) and [Robbie Vercammen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1536027/robbie-vercammen). They provides a link to Web documents that report a list of possible textual filtering to be used within the Google search form. Despite this is interesting, they don't provide an answer to the question. Hence, I studied a lot the problem and I found the following solution.

Suppose that you need to make a *una tantum* HTTP call (e.g. by a PHP class runned via CRON once a month) to Google Search in order to retrieve the search results for a particular string query, e.g. all the pages with some words (i.e. "hello" and "world") in your website (i.e. *mywebsite.com*), then you can do an HTTP get call to the following address:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=hello+world+site:mywebsite.com
```

The `q` parameter can contain the whole search query, however Google defined a *dummy proof* list of parameters.

Notice that the `AND` operator can be represented by the `as_q` parameter instead.

To get page results with one between "hello" and" world" (i.e. and OR), must be changed the query "q" parameter as:

```
q=hello+OR+world
```

while a more compact representation uses the `as_oq` parameter:

```
as_oq=hello+world
```

If one looks for the exact phrase "hello world", the `q` parameter is:

```
q="hello+world"
```

while, again, another compact representation uses the `as_epq` parameter:

```
as_epq=hello+world
```

If one looks for all the results that not contain the words "hello" and "world", the `q` parameter is:

```
q=-hello+-world
```

while, again, another compact representation uses the `as_eq` parameter:

```
as_eq=hello+world
```

Of course, `as_q`, `as_oq`, `as_epq`, `as_eq`, etc. can by combined in a unique search query as usual (i.e. by using the `&` character). Thus, for instance I can search for both words "hello" and "word" plus one between "programming" and "code" as follow here:

```
q=hello+world&as_oq=programming+code
```

One can search for a specific domain (again, *mydomain.com*) as follow:

```
as_sitesearch=mydomain.com
```

However, if you want to exclude a specific domain (e.g., because it is a spam source), you must recur to standard notation. E.g.:

```
q=hello+-site:mydomain.com
```

return all the pages with word "hello" that are not in site *mydomain.com*.

To get for a specific file type, e.g. a pdf, you can use `as_filetype`:

```
as_filetype=pdf
```

More complex search parameter can be used, as provided in [Google support docs](http://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en).
For instance, to get also results with a synonym of a word, simply use the `~` operator in front of the word, e.g.

```
q=~hello
```

Moreover, if you want to use wildcards, e.g. to get all the exact phrases that start with "hello" and end with "world", you should use the `*` operator:

```
q="hello+*+world"
```

which probably will return something like: "hello to the world" and "hello sweet world".

One can also search for specific words inside the page title or in the page url by using the following keywords (read [here](https://sites.google.com/site/resourcesandsearchstrategies/google/advanced-searching-in-google) for more details):

- intitle
- allintitle
- inurl
- allinurl

For instance, the following returns all the pages s.a. both words "hello" and "world" are in the url:

```
q=allinurl:hello+world
```

For the language of the Google GUI page (not the one of the results), one must insert into the query string the language string (e.g. `en` for English, `fr` for French, `it` for Italian, etc.) to the `hl` parameter. In other words, if one search with the English version of Google, the query string becomes as follow:

```
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=hello+world+site:mywebsite.com
```

To select a specific language, e.g. Italian, use the `lr` query parameter:

```
lr=lang_it
```

One can also select pages published in a specific geographical region by using the `cr` parameter. E.g., to find all the pages published in Italy:

```
cr=countryIT
```

Answer (score 2):

To create complex `and` / `or` queries, you can use `()` and `OR`.

For example if we want to search for

```
("tschakk buff" AND "boom bang") OR ("zata tong" AND "zong klirr")
```

The query would look like this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=("tschakk%20buff"%20"boom%20bang")%20OR%20("zata%20tong"%20"zong%20klirr")
```

Answer (score 1):

though this books title seems dangerous but anyway it will answer all your questions if u don't misuse it.

The name of the book is "Dangerous Google – Searching for Secrets" by Michał Piotrowski by some hackin9 magazine.

Wish ya luck

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to assemble your own url by manually typing the url before using it, this site should prove helpful: http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators.html

Comment: I'm going to test it. I'll give you a feedback tomorrow! Thanks, anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

[Advangle](http://advangle.com) is a nice free service where you can construct web-search queries visually and get a query string (or URL to Google and Bing) as the result.

Comment: Sorry but I tried it (it is still at beta version) and it doesn't work very well!. For instance, it seems to provide support for multi-filetype search, but the query in Google returns `q="help" filetype:pdf filetype:eps`, which gives no results, while the right query would be `q=help+filetype:pdf+OR+filetype:eps`.

Comment: It's not a mistake. Simply all conditions are connected by AND by default. So you asked to find all documents with file type EPS AND PDF which is obviously impossible.
If you need to connect them by OR - change the type of linking at the root condition group from "all" to "any".

Comment: The link is dead.